# ASP.NET VB.NET -- SQL UPDATE Command Not Working

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

I have been working on this particular issue for a couple of days, and scouring over SO, MSDN and other google searches has not proven to be of any use.  I am trying to make a simple update to a SQL table.  My SELECT and INSERT statements all work fine, but for some reason, this update will not work.  I have set breakpoints and stepped through, and the code seems to be working fine -- the Catch ex as Exception is never reached after the .ExecuteNonQuery() fires off.

Could anyone give me an idea of why I've been unable to get a SQL update?

```
Protected Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
        Dim currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)
        Dim username As String = currentUser.UserName
        Dim userId As Guid = currentUser.ProviderUserKey
        UserNameTextBox.Text = username

        ' Get Root Web Config Connection String so you don't have to encrypt it
        Dim rootWebConfig As System.Configuration.Configuration
        rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/")
        Dim connString As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings
        connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer")
        Dim conn As String = connString.ToString
        Dim commandString As String = "UPDATE UserDetails SET FirstName ='" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "' WHERE UserId ='" + userId.ToString + "'"
        Dim fname As String = FirstNameTextBox.Text

        Dim commandText As String = "UPDATE UserDetails SET FirstName=@firstname WHERE UserId=@UID;"

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(conn)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text


            ' Add UserId parameter for WHERE clause.
            command.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = userId
            ' command.Parameters("@UID").Value = userId
            ' command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", userId)
            ' Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics. 
            command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = fname
            'command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fname)
            ' command.Parameters("@firstname").Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text.ToString

            Try
                connection.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Finally
                connection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like be the user id provided is failing to match which would explain the lack of an exception and the lack of an update.

If you output the commandText statement and run it in sql server manager does it work?

Comment: I am fairly certain that the UserId matches -- my previous tries would tell me "Invalid Column Name: Brian" (where Brian is actually the value of FirstNameTextBox.Text where UserId = CurrentUserId.  

How would I do it in SQL?  Just replace @UID with the actual UserID GUID from the table?

Comment: Complicating matters -- I am hosted on GoDaddy.  I have very limited access to SQL, IIS, etc.

Comment: I'd print the currentUser.ProviderUserKey to the page, copy it, then create the statement "UPDATE UserDetails SET FirstName='TEST' WHERE UserID='YOUR GUID" and run it from your code...see if it works..

Comment: I just ran it in SQL ... 

UPDATE UserDetails SET FirstName='brianf' WHERE UserId='9F50431E-6777-42E8-8246-D4422DF50703'

The UserId was pulled directly from the UserDetails table.  It didn't work unless there were single quotes around each of the terms

Comment: After I ran it in SQL, my FirstName was set to brianf instead of Brian.  So, the query SHOULD work ..

Comment: I also did pop a texbox on there to display the UserId -- it matches as I expected it to.

Comment: Yes it should..however the contents of currentUser.ProviderUserKey must be examined and verified as being exactly right. It is possible it is being changed outside of your event handler so it no longer precisely matches what's in the table, or it may be wrong for another reason...needs verifying..

Comment: How do you recommend verifying?  When I load the page, I load all UserDetails where UserId = currentUser.ProviderUserKey -- I thought that was enough to verify that I've gotten the right UserId

Comment: Ok yes dumping it to a text box then using in the test query is enough to verify it. I'm not sure in that case... Just wanted to make sure the ID was right :)

Comment: Thanks ... Dangit, this thing is killing me!  It should be so very simple ... Why does it gotta do me dirty! :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running "command.ExecuteNonQuery()" twice, meaning the second execution will likely return 0 rows affected since you already updated what you needed to update, and that's what you're assigning to rowsAffected.  Are you sure the UPDATE isn't occurring?

Edit:  Re your comment, did you check for IsPostBack when you LoadUser? If not, when you click SaveButton, you're going to reload the existing values, and then you'll be updating with those existing values.

Comment: Yeah, I noticd that and tried it with and without that command (that was added in from a MSDN snippet) ...

I have gone into SQL and verified that the field is not being updated -- Plus, when My page loads, it calls a function "LoadUser" which retrieves latest values from the DB, and the FirstName field is never updated.  Obviously, I will update the rest of my fields after I have the firstname one working properly.

Comment: I thought I had the problem solved, because when the page refreshed, the values stayed the same -- but as it turns out, I am still not writing the values to the DB, but since I disabled FormLoad if Not isPostBack, it doesn't re-read the items from the DB.  Open SQL and validated that values are not being written.

Comment: I take it back.  You were right -- it was due to postback.  Thanks for that.  I was not writing because I had some parameters being added to the command, but I was actually using a string with embedded values.  Thats what happens when you try and meld a bunch of approaches together!

Everything seems to be on the up and up, so thanks for your help.  I will be altering the query to use params instead of variables, but I really just wanted to get it so I could update existing data in the DB.  Thanks!